# Несколько платежных сервисов в одном проекте

Tags: android

Есть некий проект. Он расположен на площадке Play Google. В него внедрена платежная система от Гугл. Есть желание распространять приложение на других площадках, но там свои платежные системы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, схему внедрения нескольких платежных систем для одного проекта.

Для себя примерно это вижу таким образом: в основном проекте используются классы и методы реализованные в некоей библиотеке. Соответственно при сборке буду указывать какую ту или иную библиотеку с различными сервисами.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gradle поддерживает генерацию в рамках одного проекта нескольких APK, фича называется `flavor`. Я делаю это приблизительно так:

```
productFlavors {
    google {
        sourceSets {"src/android/google"} //исходники специфичные для Play Market
        dimension "default"
    }
    amazon {
        sourceSets {"src/android/amazon"}  //исходники специфичные для Amazon Market
        dimension "default"
    }
}

buildTypes {

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        zipAlignEnabled true
        sourceSets {  //общие исходники для всего проекта
                java.srcDirs=['src/android/default/java/']
                manifest.srcFile 'src/android/default/AndroidManifest.xml'
                resources.srcDirs = ['src/android/default']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src/android/default']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/android/default']
                res.srcDirs = ['src/android/default/res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['src/android/default/assets']
            }
      }
   release {
        //....
   }
```

[Документация](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)

Comment: Пока не совсем понял по источникам, но спасибо за идею. Буду ее копать.